# Schema.org data in different places of HTML

Tags: html, schema.org

I am trying to setup a website for small business and I'd like to use schema.org markup as well. One trouble I encountered is how to deal with the fact that data about the business are in different places of HTML such as:

```html
<h1>Organization Name</h1>

<div>Opening hours among other things here</div>

<div>Address with a map here</div>
```

How shall I add it to schema.org? + How can I add data that don't make sense in the site, but are possible to include in schema.org (such as URL to map - it doesn't make sense on site since I use Google Maps there, but it makes sense to send link to Google Maps or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One trouble I encountered is how to deal with the fact that data about the business are in different places of HTML such as:

In this case use *itemscope itemtype* for elements like *body* or *html*.
Smth like

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">

<h1 itemprop="name">Organization Name</h1>
<meta itemprop="openingHours" content="Your openinng hours here in schema.org format - e.g.Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30">Your openinng hours here in whatever you want format for enduser
...
</body>
```

> How can I add data that don't make sense in the site, but are possible
>   to include in schema

Use *meta* tags for invisible content. Excerpt from [doc](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing)

> Sometimes, a web page has information that would be valuable to mark up, but the information can't be marked up because of the way it
>   appears on the page. The information may be conveyed in an image (for
>   example, an image used to represent a rating of 4 out of 5) or a Flash
>   object (for example, the duration of a video clip), or it may be
>   implied but not stated explicitly on the page (for example, the
>   currency of a price). 
>   ... This technique should be used sparingly. Only use meta with
>   content for information that cannot otherwise be marked up.

And example from that page

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
  <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
  <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
    Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> One trouble I encountered is how to deal with the fact that data about the business are in different places of HTML

Use the [`itemref` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemref). Example [from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#the-basic-syntax):

```
<div itemscope id="amanda" itemref="a b"></div>
<p id="a">Name: <span itemprop="name">Amanda</span></p>
<div id="b" itemprop="band" itemscope itemref="c"></div>
<div id="c">
 <p>Band: <span itemprop="name">Jazz Band</span></p>
 <p>Size: <span itemprop="size">12</span> players</p>
</div>
```

> How can I add data that don't make sense in the site, but are possible to include in schema

If the value is a string, use the `meta` element. If the value is a URI, use the `link` element. Those two elements are [allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#other-changes-to-html5) in the `body`, if they have the `itemprop` attribute.